# 3D graph in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I want to see the series more clearly (side by side). How can I achieve it?

[image]

```
Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, yAxis);
Chart1.Series["Legend1"].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, yAxis);
Chart1.Series["Legend"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
Chart1.Series["Legend1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

Chart1.Series["Legend"].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
Chart1.Series["Legend"].Color = Color.FromArgb(198, 99, 99);
// Chart1.Series["Legend"].ChartType = ;
Chart1.Series["Legend"].BorderWidth = 2;

Chart1.ChartAreas["studentChartArea"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas["studentChartArea"].Area3DStyle.LightStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.LightStyle.Realistic;
Chart1.ChartAreas["studentChartArea"].Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = 50;
Chart1.ChartAreas["studentChartArea"].Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 10;
```